# How to insert only day and month or month and year or any combination in a date field sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a date of birth field in the database which is of datatype date. I have three dropdowns for the same in my aspx page. One dropdown for day,one for month and one for year. If the user selects only day and month or month and year or any combination. How to insert that into the date field into the database.

If the user selects only the day and month or the month and the year or any combination as such. How to insert this into the database?

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you allow a user to not select a year, or atleast select a 0000 year ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

- Keep day, month and year in separate (nullable) fields in your database
- Keep a `DateTime` field in the database, populate it with "dummy" data when it's not provided, and have a separate field to indicate what information was provided

The first sounds more sensible to me - it's not like you can really do many sensible date-related queries with "19th of some month in 1976", and it means your data *accurately* represents what the user specified.

Comment: I cannot change the database structure. There is only date field. On the frontend i have three dropdowns. User can select either one,two or all the three dropdown. However i have difficulty in inserting the value in the db if the user does not select either of the field. How to insert it into a date field

Comment: @asifa: Make up the data, obviously. You *have* to have a year, month and day for any date - so use (say) January 1st 2000 as your "template" value. If they don't include a year, use 2000. If they don't include a month, use January. If they don't include a day-of-month, use 1. Of course, you're losing the information about "what the user actually entered" but that's a failure in your schema.

Comment: u are very much correct, but can u tell me a default date to set in the db as u said 1st Jan but if a user actually selected 1st Jan then there will be problems. Can u suggest a default date template. Thanks so much for your efforts

Comment: @asifa: "there will be problems" is too vague to really give you any useful feedback. You can't really pick a valid date which will never be picked by users, if they *can* pick the year. After all, if I just specify "1976" how could you possibly pick a date in 1976 which couldn't have been entered manually? As I say, your schema is basically broken for the information you need to retain.

Answer (score 0):

Don't allow user to submit answer until he selects all the field. That's the standard way. you can use validator for it.
Or else try this(i am not sure about this)
1. Keep date field null.
And/Or

2.If (txtDate.Text = "") Then
cmd.Parameters("@Date").Value = sqldatenull

Answer (score 0):

0000 isn't a valid year; firstly I'd revisit the requirements for the input form to decide what is optional and possible add validation.

If it is only the year that is optional then you could simply store 0001 as the year.

```
dt = new DateTime(Math.Max(1,dob_year), dob_month, dob_day);
```

If day and/or month are optional then a DateTime isn't the right data type  because you cannot store null values so having separate fields for day, month, year is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

A Date will always need all a day, month and a year because it refers to an actual day in the past, present or future.

All dates have to be in the range 01/01/0001 to 31/12/9999, so there is no way of storing the year 0000.

For your problem there are two options:

- Store the day the, the month and the year in three separate fields.
- Store the date in the usual way, setting the unspecified parts of the date to some default values. Then use a second field with a tinyint to store three bit flags which tell you which parts of the date are valid and which aren't